# Adding handler in <system.webServer>

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I am new to Asp.Net and I want to know if it is possible to add a handler tag in < system.web > and < system.webServer> in web.config file dynamically during design time so that I can add a handler for image.

I need this information because I'm creating an image in a c# project. I'll compile it and generate a dll for the project. By using this dll, I want to use the image in a different project. So, when I add reference to the dll in any of my new project, I would like to add the handler during design time instead of changing it manually in web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  PreApplicationStartMethod  with assembly attribute to register dynamically without adding to web.config. Add this code to your external library and it should work.

```
[assembly: System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationConfiguration), "Configure")]
namespace MyExtrarnalLibrary
{

    public   class PreApplicationConfiguration  {

        public static void Configure()
        { 
            //to register handler - handler must implement IRouteHandler
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("myspecialurl.asmx",new MyHttpHandler()));
            // if you want to register httpmodule , you can do this.
            Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(MyHttpModule));    
        }

    } 
}
```